# Why C++ string erase function in a stringstream declaration and initialization failed to work?

Tags: c++, stringstream

I've made a simple program. I'm reading a text file in the same folder as the program. The file only has one line: `" v 1.0 2.0 3.0"`.

**Problem:**

When I initialize a `stringstream` instance `ss` with a string `line`, and I use the `erase()` function to try to remove the character `'v'` from the string, it is not working. The MSVC consoles shows the same line of string:

[image]

If I remove the `.erase(0,1)` function, the output is the same.

How could this happen? It should remove the character `v`. I learn this through the OpenGL's obj loader tutorial, and they can remove it.

**Code**

```
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream filestream("textfile.txt", std::ios::in);
    std::string line = "";

    while (!filestream.eof())
    {
        std::getline(filestream, line);
        std::cout <<"getline std::string "<< line.c_str()<<std::endl;
        std::stringstream ss(line.erase(0,1));
        std::cout << "stringstream: " << ss.str() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: To me it looks like there is a leading whitespace character before the `v` which does get removed

Comment: I tried, will put the test below

Comment: Don't miss https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons

Comment: It is a good idea to surround strings with visible delimiters when you want to inspect them visually. Try `std::cout << std::quoted(line) << std::endl;`

Comment: Seems fine here when `v` is the first character of the string. I suspect in your case it is not. Add delimiters around what you print to accurately visualize whitespace. https://godbolt.org/z/6jdzsqacG As a side note, `.c_str()` is not necessary when printing a string using iostreams.

Comment: Please, do not answer in the question section. Rollbacked edit.

Answer (score 0):

After some testing, I found the reason. I made a low level mistake.
I should use a text editor that can show all the hiden blank spaces.

It looks like that there is an empty character since the initializtion of stringstream ss.
And if I remove one more characters, then it is okay.

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream filestream("textfile.txt", std::ios::in);
    std::string line;

    while (!filestream.eof())
    {
        std::getline(filestream, line);
        std::cout <<"getline std::string"<< line.c_str()<<std::endl;
        std::stringstream ss(line.erase(0,2));
        
        std::cout << "stringstream:" << ss.str() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Is it possible that book writer of the opengl book made a typo? They use
erase(0,1) for "v" for vertices data, and then use erase(0,2) for "f" for the face data

That is the mistake for not using a good text editor

Comment: Maybe it's your file that is off, and not the book.  The author of the book has no idea what you may have done to the text file.

Comment: Replace `while (!filestream.eof())` with `while (std::getline(filestream, line))` and read [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons). When you find a good editor, I recommend Notepad++, check if your file has a BOM.